# Conditional .gitignore files - adding logic to .gitignore

Tags: javascript, git, typescript, gitignore

So I have TypeScript project. The generated .d.ts and .js files can cause unnecessary merge conflicts.

However, this project is big and is currently only ~50% converted from JS to TS, so I cannot simply .gitignore all .js files. Furthermore, there are some .js files which I will never convert to .ts.

**So is there a way to conditionally ignore a file?**

The logic is of course simple:

```
ignore z.js if z.ts exists
```

Comment: Also, I kind of want .js files to be in version control, so that I don't have to rebuild stuff on target machines.

Comment: yolo rolo cholo

Answer (score 4):

> **So is there a way to conditionally ignore a file?**

No, there isn't.

> However, this project is big and is currently only ~50% converted from JS to TS, so I cannot simply .gitignore all .js files

You can. Files already tracked by Git are not affected by `.gitignore`, thus only `*.js` files generated by the build process will be ignored.

Comment: right, but if I manually add .js files to the project, they will suddenly be .gitignore, which is not what I want.

Comment: @AlexanderMills but you can still `git add -f` those new `.js` files

Answer (score 2):

**This is not possible**, `.gitignore` is a very simple file and it doesn't allow any conditional rules for ignoring file(s) or folder(s).

However, you can create different patterns to include or exclude your file(s).

Please Take a look here for help on writing `.gitignore` patterns:   [.gitignore File Docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Answer (score 2):

You can have multiple `.gitignore` files. If all your typescript files are in one directory (or one directory structure) and your `.js` files are in another, place a new `.gitignore` file inside the typescript directory that ignores javascript files.

This will only ignore javascript files in that directory and subdirectories.